# Как сделать словарь из двух списков?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, словари

Итак , у меня есть два списка uniq и fifa(по длине одинаковы). Мне нужно , чтобы каждому элементу списка uniq был наследован каждый элемент списка uniq.

p.s. к глубочайшему сожалению , я не могу придумать , как сделать данную конструкцию без костылей

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы каждому значению из списка uniq соответствовало значение из списка fifa?

Comment: да (я пишу этот текст в скобочках , чтобы обойти правила в стаке)

Comment: какое отношение pandas  к вопросу имеет?

Comment: дал понять людям  , что манипуляции с данным либом тут актуальны и могут быть использованы мной в коде

Comment: Чтобы подробнее разобраться в этой теме, рекомендую обратиться к этой статье. Здесь всё поэтапно написано и про другие темы в сфере программирования.
https://sibsisadmin.ru/kak-sdelat-slovar-iz-dvuh-spiskov-v-python/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
uniq = [1,2,3,4,5]
fifa = ['a','b','c','d','e']
uniq_and_fifa = dict(zip(uniq, fifa))
```

Comment: спасибо , я думал , что zip перемножает

Comment: Zip склеивает объекты на каждой итерации, в результате чего получается zip-объект, который можно переобразить в какой-то массив с помощью соответсвующих методов dict, list и так далее.

Comment: @SaharVkusni: zip от слова zipper (застёжка-молния) -- [сшивает половинки](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Zipper.svg): первый элемент это объединение первых элементов аргументов: `print(*next(zip('abc', 'ABC')))` -> `a A`

Answer (score 5):

Судя по описанию задачи и метке `Pandas` вам нужен Pandas.Series:

```
In [48]: uniq = np.arange(1, 11)

In [49]: fifa = np.random.choice(list('abcdefgh'), 10)

In [50]: s = pd.Series(fifa, index=uniq)

In [51]: s
Out[51]:
1     b
2     c
3     b
4     d
5     f
6     e
7     a
8     a
9     c
10    h
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

Для того, чтобы из двух списков сделать словарь, надо перебрать в цикле все индексы любого из списков (ведь длина списков одинакова):

```
for i in range(0, len(uniq)):
    #тело цикла
```

Теперь в теле цикла можно обратиться к элементам с одинаковыми индексами:
`uniq[i]` и `fifa[i]` - это ключ и значение элемента словаря, который нужно создать. Создать новый элемент словаря можно так: `uniq_and_fifa[ключ] = значение`. Объявляем пустой словарь и дописываем цикл `for`:

```
uniq_and_fifa = {}

for i in range(0, len(uniq)):
    uniq_and_fifa[uniq[i]] = fifa[i]
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]